# Convert string to date in gridview that connected to mysql

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, visual-studio, gridview

how to convert the string to date in grid view that connected to Mysql via object data source.
for CoopF_From and CoopF_To columns.
Convert.ToDateTime "shows the the date and the time, and I want only to show the date"

the code in data access layer

```
namespace Demo.CoopF
{
    public class CoopF
    {
        public string CoopF_FName { get; set; }
        public string CoopF_MName { get; set; }
        public string CoopF_LName { get; set; }
        public int CoopF_ID { get; set; }
        public string CoopF_Mobile { get; set; }
        public string CoopF_Email { get; set; }
        public string CoopF_From { get; set; }
        public string CoopF_To { get; set; }



    }
    public class CoopFDataAccessLayer
    {
        public static void UpdateCoop( int CoopF_ID, string CoopF_FName, string CoopF_MName, string CoopF_LName, string CoopF_Mobile, string CoopF_Email, string CoopF_From, string CoopF_To)
        {
            string CF = "server=localhost; userid=; password=; database=; allowuservariables=True";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CF))
            {
                string UpdateQuery = " Update coop_female SET CoopF_FName=@CoopF_FName," + " CoopF_MName=@CoopF_MName," + " CoopF_LName=@CoopF_LName," + "CoopF_Mobile=@CoopF_Mobile," + "CoopF_Email=@CoopF_Email,"+ "CoopF_From=@CoopF_From,"+"CoopF_To=@CoopF_To=@CoopF_To WHERE CoopF_ID=@CoopF_ID";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdateQuery, connection);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_FName = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_FName", CoopF_FName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_FName);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_MName = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_MName", CoopF_MName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_MName);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_LName = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_LName", CoopF_LName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_LName);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_ID = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_ID", CoopF_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_ID);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_Mobile = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_Mobile", CoopF_Mobile);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_Mobile);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_Email = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_Email", CoopF_Email);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_Email);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_From = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_From", Convert.ToDateTime(CoopF_From));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_From);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_To = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_To", Convert.ToDateTime(CoopF_To));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_To);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();

            }
        }
        public static List<CoopF> GetAllEmployees()
        {
            List<CoopF> listCoopF = new List<CoopF>();
            string CF = "server=localhost; userid=; password=; database=; allowuservariables=True";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CF))
            {
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * from coop_female", connection);
                connection.Open();
                MySqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    CoopF coop = new CoopF();
                    coop.CoopF_FName = rdr["CoopF_FName"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_MName = rdr["CoopF_MName"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_LName = rdr["CoopF_LName"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_ID = Convert.ToInt32(rdr["CoopF_ID"]);
                    coop.CoopF_Mobile = rdr["CoopF_Mobile"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_Email = rdr["CoopF_Email"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_From = rdr["CoopF_From"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_To= rdr["CoopF_To"].ToString();


                    listCoopF.Add(coop);


                }
            }
            return listCoopF;
        }

        public static void DeleteCoop(int CoopF_ID)
        {
            string CF = "server=localhost; userid=; password=; database=; allowuservariables=True";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CF))
            {
                string UpdateQuery = " Delete from Coop_female WHERE CoopF_ID=@CoopF_ID";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdateQuery, connection);
                MySqlParameter param = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_ID", CoopF_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();

            }

        }

        public static void InsertCoop(string CoopF_FName, string CoopF_MName, string CoopF_LName, int CoopF_ID, string CoopF_Mobile, string CoopF_Email, string CoopF_From, string CoopF_To)
        {
            string CF = "server=localhost; userid=; password=; database=; allowuservariables=True";
            using (MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(CF))
            {
                string UpdateQuery = " INSERT INTO Coop_female (CoopF_FName, CoopF_Mname, CoopF_LName, CoopF_ID, CoopF_Mobile, CoopF_Email, CoopF_From, CoopF_To)" + " VALUES (@CoopF_FName,@CoopF_MName,@CoopF_LName,@CoopF_ID,@CoopF_Mobile,@CoopF_Email,@CoopF_From,@CoopF_To)";
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(UpdateQuery, connection);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_FName = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_FName", CoopF_FName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_FName);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_MName = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_MName", CoopF_MName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_MName);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_LName = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_LName", CoopF_LName);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_LName);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_ID = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_ID", CoopF_ID);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_ID);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_Mobile = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_Mobile", CoopF_Mobile);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_Mobile);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_Email = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_Email", CoopF_Email);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_Email);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_From = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_From", Convert.ToDateTime(CoopF_From));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_From);
                MySqlParameter paramCoopF_To = new MySqlParameter("@CoopF_To", Convert.ToDateTime(CoopF_To));
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramCoopF_To);
                cmd.Connection.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.Connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}               

in code behind 


protected void lbInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_FName"].DefaultValue=((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtFName")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_MName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtMName")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_LName"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtLName")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_ID"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtID")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_Mobile"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtMobile")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_Email"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtEmail")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_From"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtFrom")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_To"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtTo")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.Insert();
    }
```

Comment: Looks like neither MySql nor GridView are relevant here. The question is about formatting a date.

Comment: Is the grid view a Winforms DataGridView ? In this case, you may use the CellFormatting event of the DataGridView .

Answer (score 0):

You can use following :

```
Convert.ToDateTime(CoopF_From).Date;
```

It will give you the `Date` value only

Comment: and in this part should i have to change thing?  
                    coop.CoopF_From = rdr["CoopF_From"].ToString();
                    coop.CoopF_To= rdr["CoopF_To"].ToString();

Comment: @y.kh If you have saved only the Date value in the database then there will be no need to do such a conversion. but if NOT you can change the part you mentioned.

Comment: How to change it?

Comment: also, i enabled insert a record and it gaves me error in  ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_From"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtFrom")).Text;
        ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_To"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtTo")).Text;

Answer (score 0):

As I see it, you need to represent `DateTime` values as strings containing only the date part. There is a standard format specifier for this, namely `"d"`.

The following interactive C# session illustrates the difference between `ToString()` and `ToString("d")`.

```
> DateTime.Now.ToString()
"2017-01-07 18:13:00"
> DateTime.Now.ToString("d")
"2017-01-07"
```

[More info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: where to write what you mentioned above?

Comment: You would use it instead of your `rdr["CoopF_From"].ToString()` if rdr["CoopF_From"] returns a `DateTime`. Otherwise things get more complicated. Also, if you need to sort by that column, things get more complicated.

Comment: but i don't want to show the current date, i want it to show the date that saved in the database

Comment: and in insert part, I want to make the user insert the date manually and it will save as a date in the database

Comment: Ok, just try replacing your `rdr["CoopF_From"].ToString()` with `rdr["CoopF_From"].ToString("d")` and see what happens.

Comment: it shows me only the date, thaank you. But when i insert a date to save it in the database it gives me an error in ObjectDataSource1.InsertParameters["CoopF_From"].DefaultValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("TxtFrom")).Text;